# Grabbing data between multiple date ranges in a single query

Tags: postgresql, conditional-statements, boundary

I often have to grab data from a real time database where the data is between two dates for a product. This is pretty monotonous if I'm grabbing data for the same product over and over again for different date ranges and have to switch back and forth between excel sheets. How can I combine the date ranges into a single query so my workload is lighter in excel?

<sub>This question was inspired by a co-worker who really shouldn't be allowed near databases(and now isn't)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

What actually happening when you pull a range of data is that PostgreSQL is checking for Boolean expression values against that field for the entries. If it satisfies all conditions for being considered valid it will get pulled.

#### Example in PostgreSQL

```
SELECT
    fields
FROM
    table
WHERE
    (fieldX BETWEEN lower_bounds1 AND upper_bounds1
OR
    fieldX BETWEEN lower_bounds2 AND upper_bounds2)
;
```

As you can see when you put a boundary(between statement) for your value to be compared against it evaluates to a Boolean in the end. When you want to evaluate more than one value you need to have multiple Boolean values to compare too. This means you need to decide *how* they should compare. If it's the same field, and it's in a different comparison and at least one of them needs to be true then you want to use an **OR** statement to join the two Boolean values together into a single comparison.

#### BETWEEN Statements and Ranges

**Between** is really a combination of **Less Than** and **Greater Than** in a more convenient way to write it that makes it easier to see what range the value has to be in to be considered valid.

A between statement can be rewritten in the following manner

```
SELECT
    fields
FROM
    table
WHERE
    fieldX >= lower_bounds
AND
    fieldX <= upper_bounds
;
```

#### Example of Combinations

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE
    t.field1 = value
AND
    (
        (t.field2 BETWEEN lower1 AND uppper1)
    OR
        (t.field2 BETWEEN lower2 AND uppper2)
    )
;
```

In all reality this is pretty close to the following **IF** statement

```
if(exp1 && (exp2 || exp3){
//do things here because it's valid
}
```

This example will select all rows with values meeting the first condition and any of the two in the secondary condition.

#### Why it works

The reason these concepts work is because of something called **Boolean Logic**. That's a lot to explain, but plenty of people on the internet have great guides to this. Satisfy the expressions and you can pull very complex data sets.

**Other Types of Comparisons**

More information can easily be found in the documentation for PostgreSQL but a **WHERE** clause really just looks for an expression that can evaluate to a true value. You can use conjunctions(**AND**), options(**OR**), exclusives(**XOR**<sup>1</sup>), or separations(**NAND**<sup>2</sup>) to join multiple expressions in a single query. Along with nesting conditionals in the **WHERE** clause you can create some pretty complex queries to grab exactly the data you want.

---

1: **XOR** isn't actually a part of PostgreSQL. To use something similar to it you need to join multiple boundaries together with exclusions like so

```
SELECT
A,
B
FROM
(
VALUES
    (false, false),
    (false, true),
    (true, false),
    (true, true)
)
AS data(A, B)
WHERE
    ( A and not B) or ( not A and B)
;
```

2: **NAND** means NOT AND. The difference of this and an **OR** is that it will also evaluate an all false condition as **true**

```
SELECT
A,
B
FROM
(
VALUES
    (false, false),
    (false, true),
    (true, false),
    (true, true)
)
AS data(A, B)
WHERE
    not A or not B
;
```